# Using OAuth2 in Android app to get Token for Strava API

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, appauth, strava

I'd like to enable "upload activity to Strava" in my Android app. For that I need a token. Strava uses OAuth2 and I suppose it's really not much of a problem to authenticate and get a token in a web application.

But when using it **inside a native Android app**, I have to load the authenticate page in a `WebView`. If user chooses to "login with Google", then Google auth creates a 403, because it refuses to do the login inside a WebView, [see this article](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html).

So I followed the advice to use [AppAuth for Android](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/). They claim that the process only works with OAuth-Servers prepared for communication with native apps:

> In general, AppAuth can work with any Authorization Server (AS) that supports native apps, either through custom URI scheme redirects, or App Links. AS's that assume all clients are web-based or require clients to maintain confidentiality of the client secrets may not work well.

Before spending another couple of hours searching for a solution (more like trial and error), I decided to ask you:

Is it possible to authenticate a Strava user and get the desired token (`Authenticate: Bearer abc9897...`)?

- over "login with Google"
- over "login with Facebook"
- over username + password

The problem I see is: At least when using Google login, there are 2 OAuth authentication processes involved and it has to run in the browser, not in a WebView. How can I intercept both processes and get the token at the end of the day?

Comment: you can open Strava's authorization URL in a web browser instead of a webview,,

Comment: Ok, but how would I receive the callback then? User lost in the browser?

Comment: Your callback url can be a deep link that will open in your app...

Comment: This sounds good. Is there an example out there?

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have the same question.  The discussion sounded like it was zeroing in on an answer but never published here.